# Angular 2 Service update UI on change

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I im developing an Angular2 application where I have a `ConfigurationService` and a component, that needs to register on changes on properties of this service.

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/src/core/di/decorators";
@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
    private config = {
        showDeveloperOptions: false
    }

    constructor() {}

    get isDeveloper() {
        return this.config.showDeveloperOptions;
    }


    public setDeveloperOptions(developerOptions: boolean) {
        this.config.showDeveloperOptions = developerOptions;
        console.warn("Set DeveloperOptions to " + this.config.showDeveloperOptions);
    }
}
```

my view component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'developer',
    template: `<div [hidden]="config.isDeveloper">Not a Developer</div>`,
    providers: [ConfigurationService],
})

export class DeveloperComponent {
    constructor(public config: ConfigurationService) {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I trigger `ConfigurationService.setDeveloperOptions(true)` from another service where this service got injected, it does not update the view.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Seb

Comment: How are you binding the value into your view?

Comment: [hidden]="config.isDeveloper" and config is set as a public accessible variable in the components constructor.

Comment: I could be wrong but I see config as a private member, and nothing in the constructor? I get that you're accessing that getter, for the heck of it what happens if you just declare the var as public and bind to it directly (not using the getter)?

Comment: Is the ConfigurationService you're calling to set the same instance of the service? Is it declared as a provider elsewhere and set in that other location?

Comment: What is logged as a value of this.config.showDeveloperOptions if you log in the getter?

Comment: I actually found out, that I defined it multiple times as a provider, once on the component and once on the bootstrap method, which is ofc a stupid mistake. Thanks for helping out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never deep import an Angular module. Also, the module you import is not longer there:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
```

This is just to mark the service for dependency injection, but is not the issue here.

The issue is how angular proceeds with change detection. A view should be updated only from:

1. itself
2. an input property
3. an observable

This is to guarantee a single pass is enough to process views.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
    private config = new BehaviorSubject({
        showDeveloperOptions: false
    });

    constructor() {}

    get isDeveloper() {
        return this.config.map(config => config.showDeveloperOptions);
    }

    public setDeveloperOptions(developerOptions: boolean) {
        this.config.next({showDeveloperOptions: developerOptions});
        console.warn("Set DeveloperOptions to " + developerOptions);
    }
}
```

Then you use the `async` pipe to unwrap the value. The view will update itself.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'developer',
    template: `<div [hidden]="(config.isDeveloper | async)">Not a Developer</div>`,
    providers: [ConfigurationService],
})

export class DeveloperComponent {
    constructor(public config: ConfigurationService) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, this looks like a really smart solution, that async pipe is something i havent seen before!